# Dimension of coefficents in a density equation

Tags: analysis, vector-spaces

The density throughout a composite material is given by
$T(x, y, z) = Axy^2 + Bxz^3 + Cy^2z^3,$
where $x$, $y$ and $z$ are the cartesian coordinates of the position inside the material.

(a) Find the dimensions of $A$, $B$ and $C$.

Answer (score 0):

given this equation i guess that the conditions at the limits are given ( something like T(0,y,z)= ? or T(x,0,z) = ? or T(x,y,0)= ? )
well if you have one of these you just have to make a derivation by x or y or z. or replacing the values of x or y or z.
and test all the cases and normally it should be resolved.

Comment: Maybe a small example of your own making would help you illustrate this?

Comment: to do that i want to know all the data about the problem :
i want the values around the limits (T(0,y,z) or T(x,0,z)  or T(x,y,0) ) because it depends on those conditions